# utf-16 conversion in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-16

Why the python's encode('utf-16') has a result different from what the online tools like https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/ provide? I use python 3.7.3. For example:

```
>>> ''.encode('utf-16')
b'\xff\xfe<\xd8u\xdf'
```

While result should be `b'\xD8\x3C\xDF\x75'`.

Note the UTF-8 conversion works just fine:

```
>>> ''.encode('utf-8')
b'\xf0\x9f\x8d\xb5'
```

Comment: The Python result has a byte order mark included.

Comment: Are you looking for `''.encode('utf-16be')` ?

Comment: 1. The result includes a BOM. 2. Printable bytes are printed as characters, e.g. `u` *is* `\x75`. 3. You're using a different endianness.